# Increment an array element by one

Tags: c++, arrays

(I am new to coding)
I am trying to replace an array element with itself plus 1, but it does not seem to work. In the following I am trying to replace the 3rd element:

```
int l=5;
int histogram[l];
histogram[l]={0};
histogram[2] = histogram[2] + 1;
```

It gives me the following error;

> Expected ';' after expression

histogram

Comment: Have you tried removing the odd square in the code? (It might not show up in your code editor if it's some odd unicode sign - but it shows up for me here.)

Comment: Please show us [mcve]. What is `histrogram`? Where is this line?

Comment: Also, depending on what `histogram` is, you could do `histogram[2] += 1` or `histogram[2]++` or `++histogram[2]`.

Comment: Oh, okay, first of, the compiler should also give you then line where the error happens, second, it seems like line 3 of what you showed. If you want to initialise the histogram to zero use this instead: `int histogram[5] = {0};`. Using `l` (a variable not known at compile time) for the size is not supported by the C++ standard and the 3rd line is just odd, you try to assign an array to an integer, mind you it's outside of your array too. In general though, using a `vector` would be best.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The odd square was the issue.

Comment: I would recommend to not use the letter `l` as a variable name, because it can easily be misinterpreted as the number `1`.

Comment: Note that `int x[y]; x[y] = {0};` is very different from `int x[y] = {0};`. The first one causes UB due to out-of-bounds access. The second one fills the array with zeroes (and can be shortened to `int x[y] = {};` or `int x[y]{};`).

Answer (score 1):

First of all @Elias, you have defined the size of array `histogram` to be 5. And are initializing histogram[5] to 0. But the last index of any array is `size-1...(size minus one)`, since the array index starts at zero instead of one.

And secondly, you need to initialize the entire `histogram[]` array from `histogram[0]` to `histogram[4]` before you can do any arithmetic operations like adding or subtracting them. In your code fragment,  you are trying increment `histogram[2]` by one even before it it initialized to any value.

so try this...

```
int len = 5, i = 0;
int histogram[len];
for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    histogram[i] = 0;
}
histogram[2] = histogram[2] + 1; //can also use  histogram[2] += 1; or histogram[2]++;
```

Comment: Why not just `int histogram[len] = {0};`?

Answer (score 0):

`int histogram[l];` is not C++, it's a gcc extension.

`histogram[l]={0};` is undefined behaviour, you are accessing past the end of your array. There is no way of *assigning* all the elements of a C-style array. You seem to be confusing that with the syntax to *initialise* `histogram`, which is only applicable in the declaration.

Modern C++ shuns C-style arrays. If you want a constant size, use

```
std::array<int, 5> histogram = {};
```

or if you want a size based on a runtime variable, use

```
std::vector<int> histogram(l, 0);
```